# Revert feature branch

Tags: git

I have a master and feature branch in Github. master branch does not have anything yet. My code changes committed to feature branch. I want to revert changes made in feature branch, delete that feature branch and my changes should be in my local(without loosing my changes), create another feature branch, push to remote and commit my changes to feature branch then. Could some one guide me on this.

Comment: Why not just rename the branch..?

Comment: As mentioned by OP in [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033550/2745495), this is a duplicate of [Create new branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032024/create-new-branch)

Answer (score 1):

You could

- rename the feature branch locally: `git branch -m new-name`
- push this new branch to github: `git push origin new-name`
- delete old remote branch: `git push origin :old-name`

Comment: I could not create a pull request, If I push feature branch and code in initial commit. If I create a pull request, there is nothing to compare and that is my issue. So, I am thinking to revert current feature branch without loosing changes, create another branch , push this branch to remote and commit my changes.

Comment: Basically I want to stash initial commit, create another feature branch and push it to remote then commit changes to the one created. This is to solve issue, of not able to create pull request when feature branch and code are both pushed during initial commit.

Comment: Your answer did not work out. I want to push empty feature branch and then push code.  I have deleted remote feature branch, renamed and pushed to remote from local. content also getting pushed with renamed feature branch. I only want to push feature branch first then content. Let me know if you have any question in understanding my problem, I will explain better.

Comment: Could some one provide solution on this issue. Let me know if any one does not understand my situation.